# Можно ли подключиться к нескольким устройствам через BLE с одного устройства Android?

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

У меня есть платы к которым я подключаюсь с помощью BLE, сейчас появилась необходимость подключаться к 2-м платам одновременно, возможно ли это?

Comment: да, можно, но все зависит от деталей реализации - кто является сервером, а кто - клиентом.

Comment: @metalurgus я сервер

Comment: Ну, значит, в общем слочае, если у вас нет ничего особенного - пробуйте подключить 2 сразу

Comment: На [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_%D1%81_%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC) пишут что количество устройств зависит от реализации

Comment: @AndrewRomanenko у меня только 2 устройства, в документации вроде тоже пишут что можно с несколькими, и я даже по моему понял в чем прикол, надо написать сервис на каждое подключение, но это не точно, я сейчас читаю документацию, может отвечу на вопрос сам скоро

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть приложение, которое подключается к нескольким BLE термометрам. Архитектура приблизительно такая - общий сервис, в котором содержится массив объектов-термометров, сервис висит в памяти и периодически проверяет не сдох ли кто. Внутри каждого термометра уже свой коллбэк, вот кусок класса.
Для чтения характеристик используются очереди (совет с англ. стэка) иначе все будет валиться.
Часть кода не касаемо блютуса вырезана

```
public class SmartThermometer {
public static final String ADAPTER_POSITION = "ADAPTER_POSITION";
public static final String TEMP_MAX = "TEMP_MAX";
public static final String TEMP_MIN = "TEMP_MIN";
public static final String TEMP_CURR = "TEMP_CURR";
private static final String TAG = SmartThermometer.class.getSimpleName();
public long _ID = DbModel.UNSAVED_ID;
public int mDeviceRssi;
public String mDeviceMacAddress;
public String mDeviceName;
public String mDeviceModelNumber;
public String mDeviceSerialNumber;
public String mDeviceFirmwareRevisionNumber;
public String mDeviceHardwareRevisionNumber;
public String mDeviceSoftwareRevisionNumber;
public String mDeviceManufacturer;
public String mDeviceMeasureUnits;
public int mDeviceBatteryLevel;
public long measureTime;// = -1;
public int mDeviceColorLabel = Color.BLACK;
public int mDeviceBackgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
public float intermediateTemperature = 1000f;
public float maxTemperature = -1000f;
public float minTemperature = 1000f;
public boolean selected = false;
public boolean autoconnect = true;
public int mConnectionState = BLEService.STATE_DISCONNECTED;
public boolean isNotifyEnabled = false;
public float minAlarm = -1000f;
public float maxAlarm = -1000f;
SharedPreferences preferences;
private long adapterPosition;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
private Queue<BluetoothGattDescriptor> descriptorWriteQueue = new LinkedList<BluetoothGattDescriptor>();
private Queue<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristicReadQueue = new LinkedList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        Log.e(TAG, "State changed  " + newState);
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            // intentAction = BLEService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = BLEService.STATE_CONNECTED;
            // broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.e(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.e(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" + mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = BLEService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = BLEService.STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            intermediateTemperature = 1000f;
            isNotifyEnabled = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Services discovered");
            getTemperatureByNotify(true);
            broadcastUpdate(BLEService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            //readInfoTypes();
            if (mDeviceSerialNumber == null) { //
                readInfoTypes();
            } //else {
                // broadcastUpdate(BLEService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            //getTemperatureByNotify(true);
                //getBatteryByNotify(true);
            //readInfoTypes();
            getBatteryByNotify(true);
            // }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            disconnect();
            //connect(true);
            //mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
            // disconnect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        characteristicReadQueue.remove();
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            UUID uuid = characteristic.getUuid();
            if (uuid.equals(RelsibBluetoothProfile.SERIAL_NUMBER_UUID)) {
                setmDeviceSerialNumber(characteristic.getStringValue(0).substring(0, 12));
                Log.e(TAG, "Device serial + " + mDeviceSerialNumber);
                // return;
            }
            if (uuid.equals(RelsibBluetoothProfile.MANUFACTURER_NAME_UUID)) {
                mDeviceManufacturer = characteristic.getStringValue(0).substring(0, 10);
                Log.e(TAG, "Device Manufacturer + " + mDeviceManufacturer);
                // return;
            }
            if (uuid.equals(RelsibBluetoothProfile.MODEL_NUMBER_UUID)) {
                mDeviceModelNumber = characteristic.getStringValue(0).substring(0, 10);
                Log.e(TAG, "Device model + " + mDeviceModelNumber);
                //   return;
            }
            if (uuid.equals(RelsibBluetoothProfile.BATTERY_LEVEL)) {
                mDeviceBatteryLevel = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
                Log.e(TAG, "Battery level + " + mDeviceBatteryLevel);
                //   return;
            }
            if (characteristicReadQueue.size() > 0)
                mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristicReadQueue.element());

            if (characteristicReadQueue.size() == 0) {
                BLEService.tableThermometers.save(SmartThermometer.this);
                broadcastUpdate(BLEService.EXTRA_DATA);
                //getTemperatureByNotify(true);
                //getBatteryByNotify(true);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        UUID uuid = characteristic.getUuid();
        Log.e(TAG, "onChange ");
        if (uuid.equals(RelsibBluetoothProfile.INTERMEDIATE_TEMPERATURE)) {
            intermediateTemperature = characteristic.getFloatValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_FLOAT, 1);
            switch (mDeviceMeasureUnits) {
                case MeasureUnits.Fahrenheit:
                    intermediateTemperature = round(intermediateTemperature * 1.8f + 32f, 1);
                    break;
                case MeasureUnits.Kelvin:
                    intermediateTemperature = round(intermediateTemperature - 273.15f, 1);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            if (maxTemperature <= intermediateTemperature) {
                setMaxTemperature(intermediateTemperature);
            }
            if (minTemperature >= intermediateTemperature) {
                minTemperature = intermediateTemperature;
            }
            broadcastUpdate(BLEService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            //getBatteryByNotify(true);
        }
        if (uuid.equals(RelsibBluetoothProfile.BATTERY_LEVEL)) {
            mDeviceBatteryLevel = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
            Log.e(TAG, "Battery level + " + mDeviceBatteryLevel);
            BLEService.tableThermometers.save(SmartThermometer.this);
            broadcastUpdate(BLEService.EXTRA_DATA);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Callback: Wrote GATT Descriptor successfully.");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Callback: Error writing GATT Descriptor: " + status);
        }
        descriptorWriteQueue.remove();  //pop the item that we just finishing writing
        //if there is more to write, do it!
        if (descriptorWriteQueue.size() > 0)
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptorWriteQueue.element());
        else if (characteristicReadQueue.size() > 0)
            mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristicReadQueue.element());

    }

    @Override
    public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
        super.onReadRemoteRssi(gatt, rssi, status);
        mDeviceRssi = rssi;
    }
};


private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    intent.putExtra(ADAPTER_POSITION, adapterPosition);
    //intent.putExtra(TEMP_CURR,intermediateTemperature);
    //intent.putExtra(TEMP_MAX,maxTemperature);
    // intent.putExtra(TEMP_MIN,minTemperature);
    BLEService.mActivityContext.sendBroadcast(intent);

}

public void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                            final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    BLEService.mActivityContext.sendBroadcast(intent);

}

//

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    SmartThermometer that = (SmartThermometer) o;
    return mDeviceMacAddress.equals(that.mDeviceMacAddress);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return mDeviceMacAddress.hashCode();
}

public boolean connect(boolean autoConnect) {

    Log.e(TAG, "start connecting");

    if (BLEService.mBluetoothAdapter == null || mDeviceMacAddress == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }
    //Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
    if (mDeviceMacAddress != null // && address.equals(mDeviceMacAddress)
            && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            mConnectionState = BLEService.STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    BluetoothDevice device = BLEService.mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mDeviceMacAddress); //address
    if (device == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        mConnectionState = BLEService.STATE_DISCONNECTED;
        return false;
    }

    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(BLEService.mActivityContext, autoConnect, mGattCallback);
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        mConnectionState = BLEService.STATE_DISCONNECTED;
        return false;

    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");

    mConnectionState = BLEService.STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}

public void disconnect() {

    if (BLEService.mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    intermediateTemperature = 1000f;
    broadcastUpdate(BLEService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();

}

public void close() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    //mConnectionState=BLEService.STATE_DISCONNECTED;
    mBluetoothGatt.close();
    mBluetoothGatt = null;
    Log.e(TAG, "KILL connection");
}

public void readCharacteristic(UUID serviceUUID, UUID characteristicUUID) {
    if (BLEService.mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or gatt null");
        return;
    }

    BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(serviceUUID);
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mReadCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(characteristicUUID);

    if (mReadCharacteristic == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "READ_CHAR_NULL" + mDeviceMacAddress);
        return;
    }
    characteristicReadQueue.add(mReadCharacteristic);
    //if there is only 1 item in the queue, then read it.  If more than 1, we handle asynchronously in the callback above
    //GIVE PRECEDENCE to descriptor writes.  They must all finish first.
    if ((characteristicReadQueue.size() == 1) && (descriptorWriteQueue.size() == 0)) {
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(mReadCharacteristic);

    }

}

public boolean getTemperatureByNotify(boolean enabled) {
    setCharacteristicNotify(RelsibBluetoothProfile.HEALTH_THERMOMETER_SERVICE, RelsibBluetoothProfile.INTERMEDIATE_TEMPERATURE, enabled);
    measureTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    isNotifyEnabled = enabled;

    return true;
}

public void getBatteryByNotify(boolean enabled) {
    setCharacteristicNotify(RelsibBluetoothProfile.BATTERY_SERVICE, RelsibBluetoothProfile.BATTERY_LEVEL, enabled);
    Log.e(TAG, "call get battery by notify + isnotify " + enabled);
}

public boolean setCharacteristicNotify(UUID mServiceName, UUID mCharacteristicName, boolean enabled) {

    Log.e(TAG, "CALL setCharacteristicNotify " + mCharacteristicName.toString() + " " + mDeviceMacAddress);
    if (BLEService.mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return false;
    }
    /*check if the service is available on the device*/
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GATT FAILED");
        return false;
    }

    BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(mServiceName);
    if (mCustomService == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "NOTIFY_FAILED " + mDeviceMacAddress);
        return false;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(mCharacteristicName);

    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
            RelsibBluetoothProfile.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG);
    if (enabled) {
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    } else {
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    }
    /*****/
    descriptorWriteQueue.add(descriptor);
    //if there is only 1 item in the queue, then read it.  If more than 1, we handle asynchronously in the callback above
    //GIVE PRECEDENCE to descriptor writes.  They must all finish first.

    if (((descriptorWriteQueue.size() == 1) && characteristicReadQueue.size() == 0)) {
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
    }
    //mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
    return true;
}

public void readInfoTypes() {

    readCharacteristic(RelsibBluetoothProfile.GENERIC_ACCESS_SERVICE, RelsibBluetoothProfile.DEVICE_NAME);
    readCharacteristic(RelsibBluetoothProfile.DEVICE_INFORMATION_SERVICE, RelsibBluetoothProfile.MODEL_NUMBER_UUID);
    readCharacteristic(RelsibBluetoothProfile.DEVICE_INFORMATION_SERVICE, RelsibBluetoothProfile.SERIAL_NUMBER_UUID);
    readCharacteristic(RelsibBluetoothProfile.DEVICE_INFORMATION_SERVICE, RelsibBluetoothProfile.MANUFACTURER_NAME_UUID);
    readCharacteristic(RelsibBluetoothProfile.BATTERY_SERVICE, RelsibBluetoothProfile.BATTERY_LEVEL);
}

public Long getId() {
    return _ID;
}

public void setId(Long _ID) {
    this._ID = _ID;
}

public void shutdown() {
    intermediateTemperature = 1000f;
    mConnectionState = BLEService.STATE_DISCONNECTED;
    isNotifyEnabled = false;
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    /*check if the service is available on the device*/
    BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(RelsibBluetoothProfile.RELSIBPROFILE_SERV);
    if (mCustomService == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
        return;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(RelsibBluetoothProfile.RELSIBPROFILE_SHUTDOWN);
    mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(RelsibBluetoothProfile.SHUTDOWN_THERMOMETER, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
    if (!mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic)) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
    }

}
```